# How to check whether my app has the permission in always or when in use in Android using xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, permissions, geolocation, android-permissions

I am using xamarin.forms for my app and i am using Android device. I want to check whether my app is using "Always" or "While Using the App" for location in Android.

For iOS I can able to check the permission status using *CLLocationManager.Status*.

But in android I can't able to check the permission status of "Always" or "While Using the App"

CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.LocationWhenInUse);

By using the above condition it always return granted for both "Always" or "While Using the App". I want exact permission status.
So Anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no api which can return the clear status of the location permission in android. But the user need to request two permissions, `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` in the android.

Furthermore, the different result of the two permission means different location permission status:

- Always: both the two permission are granted
- While Using the App: allow `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`
  deny `android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`

So you can do a runtime permission check to get a clear status of the location permission.